# Understand what this code, that works with bytes, does?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to understand what does the following C function do?

```
void foo(char v[4]) {
    int* p = (int*)v;
    *p = (*p & 0x000000FF) << 24 |  
         (*p & 0x0000FF00) << 8  | 
         (*p & 0x00FF0000) >> 8  | 
         (*p & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
}
```

The possible solutions, by assuming that `sizeof(int)` is 4, are four.

1. computes a checksum of all bytes of array v <- No, I tried the code putting in the array the words "a,b,c,d" and "d,c,b,a", the results are differentù
2. reverses the content of array `v` <-The function
3. rotates the content of array `v`
4. the code is wrong <- the syntax of the code isn't wrong

Comment: You missed: "5. invokes UB, by ignoring alignment requirements". So probably 4. is the answer.

Comment: 4. The code is wrong. Aside from a potential alignment problem as alk notes, it is subject to integer overflow in the first left shift and implementation-defined behavior when shifting negative values in the last right shift, even assuming an `int` is four `char` *etc.*. (I would write this as an answer, but this is one of those bad teaching questions that likely intends the answer to be 2.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil.: I was also thinking about aliasing but `char*` aliases with other types or I am getting it misinterpreted? or missing something?

Comment: @coderredoc: C allows you to convert a pointer to any object to a pointer to a character type. That does not mean you can convert a pointer to a character type to a pointer to any object type. (Although, if you know the pointer does actually point an actual object of type X, then it is okay to convert it back to a pointer to type X.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil.: Well the thing is I am trying to look for the standard which says it - if you have that please be kind enough to let me know.

Comment: @EricPostpischil.: I guess this you are referring.. *A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned68) for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.*

Comment: @coderredoc: Most of the rules for conversions of pointers are in 6.3.2.3. Paragraph 7 addresses converting to a pointer to another type and back and converting to a pointer to a character type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil.: The first line says -if there is no alignment issue then back and forth conversion is good enough. `char*` is aligned with other object type. And so it is alright to do that provided sizeof int = 4

Comment: @EricPostpischil & @coderredoc, sometimes I find the language in the specification a little hard to understand. Have you example where alignment is and issue?  Like `(char*) x` where `x is a pointer to a `struct somestruct`? Is that what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `int* p = (int*)v;` you can access now the bits in `v` as if they were
the bits of an integer. But in this case, it is used to access the 32 bits
without having to cast from `char` to `int` to `char` in all the swaps.

```
(*p & 0x000000FF)
```

returns you the first 8 bits (the least significant) [0 - 7]

```
(*p & 0x0000FF00)
```

returns you the next 8 bits [8 - 15]

```
(*p & 0x00FF0000)
```

returns you the next 8 bits [16 - 23]

```
(*p & 0xFF000000)
```

returns you the last 8 bits (most significant) [24 - 31]

This is basically doing: `v[0]`, `[v1]`, etc.

The `<< x` bits are left shifting, `<< 24` means that it moves all bits 24
spaces to the left. The `|` makes an bitwise OR operation

```
(*p & 0x000000FF) << 24
```

Moves the bits [0-7] to the [24 - 31] position

```
(*p & 0x0000FF00) << 8
```

Moves the bits [8-15] to the [16 - 23] position

```
(*p & 0x00FF0000) >> 8
```

Moves the bits [16 - 23] to the [8 - 15] position

```
(*p & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
```

Moves the [23 - 31] to the [0 - 7] position.

It is reversing the order of the bytes pointed by `v`.

**edit**

Like others have already pointed out, this reversing will only work in
environments where the size of a `char[4]` is the same as the size of an `int`.
Where those are different, the code becomes incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It interpretes a char[4] as integer and swaps it around:

```
(*p & 0x000000FF) << 24 == masks the lowes byte and puts it as highest byte
(*p & 0x0000FF00) << 8  == mask the 2nd lowest byte and puts it one higher  
(*p & 0x00FF0000) >> 8  == masks the 2nd highest byte and shifts it one down
(*p & 0xFF000000) >> 24 == masks the highes byte and moves it to the lowest
all or-ed together it swaps your char array around.
```

It goes from `['a','b','c','d']` to `['d','c','b','a'].`

And it smells. Badly.

Use a `char` as temp and swap the elements of the arary using the temp is much more clear in "*what does this*" and much saver then this char-array to int pointer bitshift casting - what happens if you are on a system where char is 8 bits and int is 64 ?

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks for the blunder pointer, meant bits. I am not firm in C specifications, just wanted to bring across its a bad idea what (s)he does.